# Problem in resizing controls (.Net 2008, Winforms, VB.Net, C#.Net)

Tags: .net

we all know how to dock or anchor controls so that they resize themselves accordingly when a form is resized.
It works fine till we have rows of controls on left and right size of the form. But what if have three columns (Columns as in visual sense. I'm not talking about any column control containing other controls) of controls?

For example a form having a bunch of controls in the left side, a bunch in the middle and a bunch in the right. There may be a few more bunches in the middle. Now while resizing the form, I want the controls to resize accordingly as well as change their positions to make space for the previous bunch of controls that are resizing.

I mean, while the user increases the form size horizontally, the controls of the second bunch should resize and at the same time they should move right because the controls of the first bunch are increasing horizontally too. When the user decreases the form size horizontally the same thing should occur in the reverse order.

I can manage it somehow using nested splitcontainers but that's too cumbersome. I would like to know if there's some better way to achieve it, like setting some property etc.?

Please help.

Please feel free to ask if my post isn't comprehensible.

Regards.

Comment: are you using winforms or WPF?

Comment: First of all, trying to get a mental picture of 3-column controls that you are talking about, its a bad design. Secondly, your question is too general. Try rephrasing or give some particular situation where you are facing this issue. Also, read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @Scott: the title says Winforms ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx), it's really intuitive to use, however there's a bunch of useful examples and walkthrough at the end of the [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I worked with till late last night. Though it's time consuming but it resolved my issue. Thanks digEmAll.

Comment: @priyamtheone: glad to be helpful :)